# HTTPS traffic doesn't work with VPN and Proxy

Tags: ssl, https, vpn, iptables, little-proxy

I have:

1. VPN server (SoftEther), to which I connected.
2. IP Tables rules to send all traffic from VPN to Proxy server.
3. Proxy server (Java). I use LittleProxy https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy. It doesn't intercept HTTPS traffic.

All these items connected like this:

> VPN client ===> VPN server ===> Proxy server ===> Intenet

HTTP traffic works fine, but HTTPS doesn't.

When I try to go to https://google.com, I see an error in Chrome:

> `This site can't provide a secure connection`

When I connect browser directly to the Proxy server - HTTPS works fine
When I connect only to VPN server - HTTPS works fine.

The same problem appears, if I switch VPN to OpenVPN.

After sniffing traffic I identified that HTTPS requests are trying to go via HTTP protocol to HTTPS address. It seems to be some issues with redirect, since when I just go to www.google.com, after 2 redirects (generated by google) I am able to reach google via https, but when I enter https://google.com - error.

In Wireshark I got 400 error:

> `Expert Info (Warning/Security): Unencrypted HTTP protocol detected over encrypted port, could indicate a dangerous misconfiguration.`

My IP Tables rules:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  ip-192-168-200-0.ec2.internal/24  anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:172.31.64.145:9090
DNAT       tcp  --  ip-192-168-200-0.ec2.internal/24  anywhere             tcp dpt:https to:172.31.64.145:9090

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-192-168-200-0.ec2.internal/24  anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-192-168-200-0.ec2.internal  anywhere
```

Where 172.31.64.145:9090 - IP of Proxy server.

VPN server and Proxy servers run on the same AWS instance.

Comment: Did you get any way to intercept the HTTPs requests?